# How to make the parent element in a dropdown menu item have visible focus using only HTML

Tags: html, css, tabs, focus, accessibility

Im trying to make the parent element in a dropdown menu have visible focus when tabbed over for accessibility concerns. However, for some reason I do not have access to the css file so I need to make this happen with HTML. Is there even a way to do this? The code is looking something like this right now:

```
<li class = dropdown
class = "dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
```

Im sorry if this question is a little vague im not sure how to go about this

Comment: Sorry, but what does "visible focus" mean?

Comment: If you are saying that dropdown is not visible on your button, please refer to the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns

Comment: He means a visible focus ring / indicator. Just use inline `<style>` tags then if you can't edit the CSS file. Assuming you don't have a content security policy set that blocks inline styles it will work fine. Either that or fix whatever problem is stopping you accessing the CSS files as that is the correct way to fix this (I would spend your time on that as you are probably going to need to change CSS in the future and doing it inline on each page is a maintainability nightmare). Perhaps raise a question  about your CSS access and then you can do this easily.

Comment: That is possible as well however would the style tag work in a way that the focus ring only appears when tabbed over? @GrahamRitchie

Comment: just do `<style>.dropdown:focus{outline: 2px solid #333;}</style>`. Place it above the first instance of the dropdown and it will behave as if you had added the style in the CSS. You may need to make the selector more specific or as a worst case (as this is a hack anyway) use `!important` in your CSS rule. That should only focus the dropdown when it has focus and not surrounding items. `:focus` will only be applied if an item is currently focused (what you are calling "tabbed over").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that your element is currently not focusable. list elements are not focusable by default, so you should first make it focusable by adding to it tabindex="0"

```
<li aria-haspopup="true"
    class = dropdown
    data-toggle="dropdown" 
    tabindex="0"><!-- li content --></li>
```

Now you should see the browser's default focus ring.
There is no option to use pseudo classes (e.g. :focus) on an inline style, so if you don't have access to the CSS file, and adding a <style> to the top of the HTML file is also not an option you can change the style attribute using inline javascript.

```
<li aria-haspopup="true"
    class = dropdown
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    onfocus="this.style.outline = '2px solid red'" 
    onblur="this.style.outline = 'none'" 
    tabindex="0"><!-- li content --></li>
```